# Creating one line from two (Bash)

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I've been playing with grep, awk and sed for sometime but I'm a bit stuck with this.

I've managed to get a file with the following format (dummy data):

```
Datacentreone
1.1.1.1.

Datacentretwo
2.2.2.2

Google 
8.8.8.8
```

But I need to get it on single lines like such:

```
Datacentreone 1.1.1.1
Datacentretwo 2.2.2.2
Google 8.8.8.8
```

I could write something in Perl or PHP to do it for me, but I'd like to learn whether it's possible to do something like this easily with just command line tools, or failing that what it'd look like using BASH?

Comment: This gnu awk should do:  `awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'  file`

Answer (score 2):

Through GNU awk,

```
$ awk -v RS="\n\n" '{print $1,$2}' file
Datacentreone 1.1.1.1.
Datacentretwo 2.2.2.2
Google 8.8.8.8
```

Here the Record separator is set to `\n\n` ie; a blank line. This overwrites the default value `\n` of `RS` variable. So awk considers one or two or more lines as single record until a blank line is found.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If you wouldn't mind could you briefly explain how that works?

Comment: You can replace the `-v RS="\n\n"` with just nothing, like this: `awk -v RS= '{print $1,$2}'`  Then it also work if there are three blank lines etc. You should also mention that your solution needs `gnu awk` due to multiple characters in Record Selector.

Comment: What is `{$1=$1}` do here?

Comment: It reconstruct the data using default `FS` as separator between every field in the record.